# How to deploy multiple Spring boot application with embedded tomcat on a single server

Tags: azure, configuration, cloud, load-balancing

I have developed 2 applications in spring boot with embedded tomcat. I have one cloud server (Azure) and i have run both the applications in that server. First app running in port 80 and other one in 81. I have domain name registration in GoDaddy For example First app is www.abc.com and the second one is www.xyz.com. How do i configure in azure console that when request comes from  www.abc.com then port 80 should serve the request else request would be served by 81.  Please help me out configuring deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by implementing User Defined Routes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview

Additionally, Azure offers Load Balancers and Traffic Mangers that you could implement as well to manage the traffic.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/load-balancer/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/